# Data entered is not writing to file

Tags: java

I am attempting to create and write to a .txt file so that another program can open and read it. The problem is that the entered data is not being written to the file created. It is a blank .txt document.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java. io.*; //import class for file input.
public class inventoryStock
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    //Declarations
    String[] itemName = new String [10];
    double[] itemCost = new double [10];
    double[] inStockNumber = new double [10];
    int counter = 0;
    //End declarations

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
     //Open output file.
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("updatedStock.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);


      do
      {
        System.out.print("Enter item name");
        pw.println();
        itemName[counter] = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter item cost");
        pw.println();
        itemCost[counter] = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter Number in stock");
        pw.println();
        inStockNumber[counter] = input.nextDouble();

        counter += 1;
      }while(counter<10);
        pw.flush();

    pw.close();
    System.exit(0);
  } //End of main method
} //End of InventoryStock class.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You need to show us the actual code if you want help with your problem.  Off the top of my head, maybe you are not flushing the buffer out to disk.

Comment: why is there an extra '{' before `do` and extra '}' before `pw.close();`?

Comment: I am a beginner and got blasted for not having curly braces last time. Also Imran, I am attempting to get the input in the detail loop. Before I added the scanner item I just got ten entries for "Enter item name" "Enter item cost" "Enter Number in stock"

Comment: you're storing the input into `itemName`, `itemCost`, and `inStockNumber`, but it is never written to file with `pw.write`, all `pw` does is add new lines currently

Comment: quidproquo, How would I go about making it write to the file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't really write what you want to file. You can try the code below.

```
pw.println(itemName[counter] + ", " + itemCost[counter] + ", " + inStockNumber[counter]);
```

Two recommendations to you.

1. Since the size 10 is everywhere in your code. You'd better extract it to a single variable for better maintainability.
2. Please follow the [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) of java. For your case, the first letter of class name should be capitalized. Use InventoryStock instead of inventoryStock.

The entire code is like below, hope it will help. Thx.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*; //import class for file input.

public class InventoryStock {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        int size = 10;
        // Declarations
        String[] itemName = new String[size];
        double[] itemCost = new double[size];
        double[] inStockNumber = new double[size];
        int counter = 0;
        // End declarations

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Open output file.
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("updatedStock.txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        {
            do {
                System.out.print("Enter item name");
                itemName[counter] = input.next();
                System.out.print("Enter item cost");
                itemCost[counter] = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Enter Number in stock");
                inStockNumber[counter] = input.nextDouble();

                pw.println(itemName[counter] + ", " + itemCost[counter] + ", " + inStockNumber[counter]);

                counter += 1;
            } while (counter < size);
            fw.flush();
        }
        fw.close();
        System.exit(0);
    } // End of main method
} // End of InventoryStock class.
```

Comment: This is also a great way to get what I am looking for. So what I had was wrong but it was not as bad as I had originally thought. You guys are great thanks so much for your help Gearon @Gearon

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to actually tell `PrintWriter` to write to file or else it won't do anything even though you grab the user's input with `input.next()`. Try something like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
//Open output file.
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("updatedStock.txt");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw, true);

do
{
    System.out.print("Enter item name");    
    itemName[counter] = input.next();
    pw.write(itemName[counter]);
    pw.println();

    System.out.print("Enter item cost");
    itemCost[counter] = input.nextDouble();
    pw.write(String.valueOf(itemCost[counter]));
    pw.println();

    System.out.print("Enter Number in stock");
    inStockNumber[counter] = input.nextDouble();
    pw.write(String.valueOf(inStockNumber[counter]));
    pw.println();

    counter += 1;
}while(counter<10);

pw.flush();
pw.close();
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: That did the trick thanks so much for the help. I am still trying to learn all these tricks and the language used to get my desired effects. I appreciate it.@quidproquo